# What to do when a question was closed because of misundertanding

Tags: discussion

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802007/access-violation-in-printing-out-float-value-using-print) in which I first think about a simple error of OP and asked for a MVCE. OP answered it could not give one, and I voted to close.

Meanwhile two other comments gave the point that :

- it was an embedded system
- it was in kernel mode

And I realized that OP could not post a MVCE - to test a kernel problem you must compile and test in kernel mode ... And the error actually made sense : kernel modes often have limitations

Of course it was already in original post, but I was not cautious enough on it.

I wanted to retract my close vote, by it was too late and the question was already *on hold*. I suppose that other close voters may have read the question as I first had.

I've already voted for re-open of the question, but I wonder what is the best pratice for that kind of case :

- simply vote for re-open and pass
- edit the post to make clear why it was closed by misunderstanding
- ask OP to to the edit
- ask for a moderator to re-open

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> simply vote for re-open and pass

You *could* do this, but if the question is so unclear that so many of its readers felt it should have been closed then I wouldn't suggest it.  Future readers are likely to treat the question just as you had at first.

> edit the post to make clear why it was closed by misunderstanding

This is a great idea, as it actually solves the problem that caused the question to be closed.  You should of course do this *in addition* to voting to reopen.

> ask OP to to the edit

This isn't as good as just editing it yourself, but if you are unsure of how to phrase it better, then perhaps this is the best that you're capable of doing.  If you don't have time to do the edit yourself this is better than nothing, but not by a lot.

> ask for a moderator to re-open

The flag would just be declined, as reopening is something that the community is quite capable of handling on its own.  Don't waste everyone's time by flagging.

Comment: I was unsure whether it was OK to edit someone else post with an important change, even if for constructive reasons. But I do agree with your arguments.

Comment: @SergeBallesta What would be the point in letting you edit posts at all if not to make changes like this?  You're greatly improving the quality of the post without making any changes to the actual semantics of the question.